# Convert u8 array to base64 string in Rust

Tags: arrays, string, rust, type-conversion, base64

I have an array of `u8` in Rust. How would I go about converting these to a `String` representing them as base64?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please note that the [`base64::encode`](https://docs.rs/base64/0.21.0/base64/fn.encode.html) function has been deprecated.

From version 0.21.0 the preferred way to achieve the same result would be

```rust
use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u8> = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    println!("{}", general_purpose::STANDARD.encode(&data));
}
```

Comment: gpt4 did not get the memo yet. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Remember to add `base64 = "0.21.7"` (or higher) to Cargo.toml.

Answer (score 12):

What you're looking for is the `base64` crate, particularly its [`encode()`](https://docs.rs/base64/0.10.1/base64/fn.encode.html) function. Usage is [pretty straightforward](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b3e680312bf8eb672617917b9c6e9c3):

```
extern crate base64;

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u8> = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    println!("{}", base64::encode(&data))
}
```